# go mongo driver update unable to set array of objects to null

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I have documents similar to this document in my mongo db

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5cbf416ec6490b9baff4d284"),
    "rewards" : [ 
        {
            "percent" : NumberLong(100),
            "promotion_id" : "promotest"
        }
    ],
    "eligible_for": ["XYZ","ABC"]

}
```

When I updated with a proper document then it is updating the document properly

But when I pass rewards, eligible_for as null then eligible_for getting updated to null but rewards not getting updated to null

```
{
    "rewards" : null,
    "eligible_for": null

}
```

then the newly updated document

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5cbf416ec6490b9baff4d284"),
    "rewards" : [ 
        {
            "percent" : NumberLong(100),
            "promotion_id" : "promotest"
        }
    ],
    "eligible_for": null

}
```

This is the query I am using to update the document using mongo-go-driver.
`r.PollingGameCollection.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": poll.RawId}, M{"$set": poll})`

Objects are:

```
type PollingGame struct {

    RawId        *objectid.ObjectID   `json:"-" bson:"_id,omitempty"`

    Rewards     *[]Reward `json:"rewards,omitempty" bson:"rewards,omitempty"`

   EligibleFor  []string `json:"eligible_for,omitempty" bson:"eligible_for, omitempty"`

}
```

```
type Reward struct {
    Percent     int    `json:"percent,omitempty" bson:"percent,omitempty"`
    PromotionId string `json:"promotion_id,omitempty" bson:"promotion_id,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Your MongoDB Object is not valid JSON. Why are the quotes around eligible_for missing?

Comment: What is the value of `poll` in `r.PollingGameCollection.UpdateOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": poll.RawId}, M{"$set": poll}`?

Answer (score 5):

First: you have an extra space in the `bson` tag value of `PollingGame.EligibleForbson"`, remove that: `bson:"eligible_for, omitempty"`.

If you remove that space, you'll notice it doesn't even set `eligible_for` to `null` anymore.

And the reason is because you use the `,omitempty` option. This tells the driver to exclude the field if its value is `nil` (the zero value). So you want to update, but these fields will not be included in the `$set` operation, so they won't change.

If you remove the `,omitempty` option, it will work:

```
type PollingGame struct {
    RawId       *primitive.ObjectID `json:"-" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Rewards     *[]Reward           `json:"rewards,omitempty" bson:"rewards"`
    EligibleFor []string            `json:"eligible_for,omitempty" bson:"eligible_for"`
}
```

(Note I also changed `objectid.ObjectID` to [`primitive.ObjectID`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID) as that is the type you have to use for MongoDB object IDs.)